# AsyncTask - onPostExecute is not called

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask, httpclient

I'm working on one project and I need to call one `AsyncTask`, but the `onPostExecute` method is not called.

This is my class:

```
public class WebService extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private ArrayList<SimpleObserver> listeners;
    private int responseCode;
    private String message;
    private String response;
    private String URL;

    public WebService() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<SimpleObserver>();
    }

    public void addListener(SimpleObserver obs) {
        listeners.add(obs);
    }

    public void removeListener(SimpleObserver obs) {
        listeners.remove(obs);
    }

    public void notifyListener(String s) {
        for (SimpleObserver listener : listeners)
            listener.onChange(s);
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //notifyListener("A calcular");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            HttpParams my_httpParams = new BasicHttpParams(); 
            final String proxyHost = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultHost();
            final int proxyPort = android.net.Proxy.getDefaultPort();
            if(proxyPort != -1)
            {
              my_httpParams.setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort));            
            }

            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(my_httpParams);
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            Log.d("URL serviço HttpGet", url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }

                Log.d("RESPOSTA do web service", response);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                response = e.getMessage();
                Log.e("ERRO de respota", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.d("onPostExecute Serviço", result);
        notifyListener(result);
    }
}
```

I have created this method:

```
public void executeService(String param) {
        try {
            Log.d("Entrar", "no serviço");
            s.execute(new String [] {URL+param});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Erro ao aceder ao web service", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

to call the task.

these are the results of Log

```
08-28 17:47:21.936: D/URL serviço HttpGet(2055): http://192.168.56.1:8080/pt.Agile21.Acerola.WebService/rest/acerola?id=g;ana@eu.com
08-28 17:47:22.456: D/RESPOSTA do web service(2055): ana;ana@eu.com;pass;0
08-28 17:47:22.456: D/RESPOSTA do web service(2055): ana;ana@eu.com;pass;0
```

As you can see I have all the results of doInBackground(). :S

Someone can help me to understand which is the problem?

Something that I saw now looking for the Log files.. my onPostExeute method returns when I finish my app on purpose.. it is not normal.. :S can someone help me?

Comment: I have created this method to call:
public void executeService(String param) {
  try {
   Log.d("Entrar", "no serviço");
   s.execute(new String [] {URL+param});
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
   Log.e("Erro ao aceder ao web service", e.getMessage());
  }
 }

Comment: Does the `doInBackground()` method get executed?

Comment: I have put above the calling method.

Comment: Yes.. I can get the response in Log.d()

Comment: Do you have get any error trace in LogCat?

Comment: no.. i didn't! I get the response in log on the android side but when I call the notify inside the onpostExecute it dind't do nothing

Comment: Is the 'onPostExecute Serviço' message logged ?

Comment: No! the 'onPostExecute is not executed

Comment: If you remove the logic inside `doInBackground()`, does it still hang?  I want to say your http requests are permanently blocking or blocking for a really long time so you're never returning.

Comment: If I understand your question... the request is not blocking becouse I can see this menssage Log.d("RESPOSTA do web service", response); So.. I think the problem is not there right?

Comment: without the logic is the same! I can't get the response of onPostExecute method

Comment: How you create your task object? Try new WebService().execute(new String [] {URL+param})

Comment: I tried your way and didn't work! :S I have One class like UserDAO and then I create a Webservice Object. then on the executeService method I call the execute of my object... But I tried your way and didn't work! :S Really I don't understand the problem!

Comment: Strip it down to bare minimum, i.e. nothing but the Log statements, and return "" from your doInBackground().  Then instantiate the object: new WebService().execute(new String[] {""});  If it all runs properly, put your code back in and DEBUG it.

Comment: I already made it.. if I don't put nothing the app give the same result. I can't execute onPostExecute()

Comment: Are you starting the AsyncTask in the UI thread?

Comment: I'm using a MVC pattern. So I call it on controller, the controllwer is called by the activity and I have Observers too!